# Minecraft over a local router?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, wifi

I'll be traveling with a friend this summer, and we'll have upwards of 20 hours total waiting in airports, and we're both avid minecraft players.

What I want to know is, would it be worth my while to buy a cheap router to carry around and plug in to electrical outlets at airports in order for us to be able to play online together?

I'm not married to this idea, so if you can think of a better way for us to do this, aside from using airport wifi which may or may not be available, please let me know! :)

Comment: a simple cross over cable (or just a regular cable even) might suffice, just ensure the laptops can see each other and don't conflict on their IPs

Comment: @ratchetfreak so, is that just a regular ethernet cable that we plug into out laptops?

Comment: yep, you might wish to test that out first though so you know the settings to use ;)

Comment: @ratchetfreak has the right idea here. I've done this before to play SMP. It's a lot easier than a router.

Comment: @SaintWacko It does sound like an easier solution. Would there be any special settings I'd have to look into? Probably should have mentioned this in the OP, but I'm on OSX and my friend's on windows.

Comment: @spoonless Ah... That might be interesting. I don't have any experience with that. You might just have to try it and see.

Comment: I'll do that when I have access to a windows machine then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

a better way would be to connect your laptops together with a standard ethernet cable (though a X-over might be required depending if the hardware supports it), and use static IPs or have one of them act as a DHCP host over the wired network

I suggest you get together before hand to work out the kinks before you go through MC withdrawal for the trip ;)

to play with a third person you'll need a [hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub) at the minimum but a switch or router will work as well

Comment: What about authenticating with the minecraft servers? Isn't that required for LAN play?

Comment: I thought you can do offline play on LAN, worst comes to worst you start a server on one of the laptops and disable account verification

Comment: I get an "End of Stream" error when trying to connect to a LAN world when both clients are in offline mode. Logging them both in properly makes the LAN world connection work again. I suspect that the correct answer to this question will involve setting up a standalone server with account verification disabled.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Someone else mentioned DHCP in their answer, why is this significant? 

And I reckon we should be able to "Open to LAN" when offline. As long as there's SOME sort of network, whether LAN, Ethernet, Wifi, Or internet, it shouldn't pose a problem right? But I'll check this out when I can.

Comment: @spoonless it's to ensure that the IPs the 2 computers assign themselves don't clash

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Ethernet cable and see if the LAN mode works. You might have to tether your phone to get DHCP working or set Static IPs on each of the machines.

Otherwise yes, a cheap router would work.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to create some sort of wired adhoc network for that to work? And I'm confused, what does my phone have to do with this?

Comment: What about authenticating with the minecraft servers? Isn't that required for LAN play?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an Ethernet cable. If you play 1.6.4 or earlier, it will work fine, regardless. Also, an ip clash is extremely uncommon. If you are playing a version after 1.6.4 and you can't automatically see your friends lan world (or vice-versa);
DO THIS ON THE COMPUTER THAT IS BEING CONNECTED TOO, NOT FROM:
(Windows)
Find command prompt
Type in "ipconfig" Find the Ethernet ipv4
Find what port the game is being hosted on(look in the chat on the computer that is hosting)
Connect to that computer in the "Direct Connect" and type in the ipv4 which should resemble xxx.xxx.xxx.xx(x) and follow with :(the port number). Thus, it should look something like this example:
192.168.157.31:25565
NOTE: the 31 on the end could be 3 digits instead of 2, I.e. 
31.... or 315 or 562, etc.